# Alternative for Wilcoxon Test?

Tags: statistical-significance, p-value, nonparametric, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test, wilcoxon-signed-rank

I'm ending my Master's Thesis, and I'm trying to figure out which test to use to calculate the significance of my data.

Basically, we measured the Free Kick biomechanical parameters of several football players in different pitch zones.

I was going to perform a Wilcoxon test, seeing as the data is not normally distributed, but the number of Free Kicks is not the same for each zone, and N would have to be the same between zones for it to work.

Basically, which test should I use to compare my parameters between pitch zones?

Comment: Hi Pedro. Welcome to Cross Validated. Firstly, could you state what hypothesis you are supposed to be testing? Secondly, one Wilcoxon test assumes the data is paired while other one is applicable as two sample procedure. Perhaps a bit more clarity would be appreciable.

Comment: The structure of your data is not quite clear to me. So there are several parameters for a single free kick, and there are several players who kicked these free kicks, and some or most or even all players have more than one free kick in the data? And now you want to compare free kick parameters over different zones? How many players, free kicks, parameters, zones do you have?

Comment: The Wilcoxon(-Mann-Whitney) **rank sum test** does not assume equal sample sizes (it is a non-parametric analog to the unpaired *t* test).

Comment: I think it would help to phrase your question without using the word "significant". That word has multiple meanings and often leads to confusion among people new to statistical thinking.